# Problem with Repository and Keys

Tags: package-management, ppa, repository, software-sources, gnupg

I wanted to update my I2P software and was following the steps provided in the official I2P  website (https://geti2p.net/en/download/debian):

1. Open a terminal and enter:
   **sudo apt-add-repository ppa:i2p-maintainers/i2p**
   This command will add the PPA to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and fetch the gpg key that the repository has been signed with. The GPG key ensures that the packages have not been tampered with since being built.
2. Notify your package manager of the new PPA by entering:
   **sudo apt-get update**

From this step this started appearing in the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu lunar InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB9660B9EB2CC88B
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu lunar InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried to deal with this problem through different methods but to no avail.

I've tried adding the key from the ubuntu server but ran into various problems using the VIM editor (couldn't paste the gpg from the web to the terminal) and when simply creating the text file "manually" I coulnd't use the terminal to find the text file and add it to the trusted.gpg.d.

DISCLAIMER: I discovered that I actually didn't need to update because it was in the lastest version already so I figured I could just delete the key but I can't find it anywhere. I tried locating the key using **sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d:debian.list** I also couldn´t find the repository so I could delete it.

I tried finding the solution here on askubuntu but to no avail.

When trying to put the file into the trust.gpg.d this appeared:

```
wget -O - http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
--2022-12-14 20:29:38--  http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease.gpg
Resolving ppa.launchpad.net (ppa.launchpad.net)... Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

When trying to deleted the file this appeared (4 times):

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 393, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 356, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 338, in get_ppa_info
    raise ShortcutException('\n'.join(msg) + "\n" +
softwareproperties.shortcuts.ShortcutException: Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~i2p-maintainers/ubuntu/i2p'.
ERROR: '~i2p-maintainers' user or team does not exist.
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve this problem...What can be causing it?

Comment: You aren't using Ubuntu. What exactly is that "lunar"?

Comment: @ChanganAuto lunar lobster is an upcoming release (23.04) which is no doubt part of the problem

Comment: so what happened is that I downloaded a repository that is not supported with 22.04? That's why I can't find it?

Comment: It sounds like the OP is using an official Ubuntu flavor but trying to install unsuitable software. Is unsuitable software off-topic?

Comment: How can I deal with that? I'm really lost...